# There is a group of 6 asteroids, numbered from 1 to 6, rotating around the Sun...

Tags: probability

For
any pair of distinct indices i, j from {1, 2, . . . , 6}, let Ei,j be the event that within the next 10 years from now
the asteroids i and j collide with each other due to gravitational influence of the planets (so, Ei,j = Ej,i).

The
collision necessarily destroys this pair of asteroids (so that, in particular, a given asteroid may collide with
at most one other asteroid in its lifetime; simultaneous collisions of three or more asteroids are prohibited).
Assume that P(Ei,j ) = 0.05 for any i 6= j, and that for every sequence of 6 distinct indices i, j, k, l, m, n, the
events Ei,j , E,k,l, Em,n are mutually independent. What is the probability that, after the 10 years elapsed,
there will be exactly 4 asteroids left in the group

(i.e. exactly one pair of asteroids is destroyed due to a
collision)? (the definition of the events Ei,j implies that Ei,j ∩ Ei,k = ∅ for any triple of distinct indices
i, j, k. The problem is solved by representing the event {4 asteroids left in the group} in terms of Ei,j ’s using
set-theoretic operations: intersections, differences, complements, unions, combined with probability estimates
for events of the form Ei,j ∩ Ek,l and Ei,j ∩ Ek,l ∩ Em,n which are implied by the independence.)

I am honestly so god damn stumped on where to on the problem I am desperate for some direction and somewhere to start...

I need to somehow find

number of scenarios where one collision occurs / total number of scenarios

SOS

Comment: Please use Mathjax!

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to imagine that each pair, of which there are ${6 \choose 2}=15,$ throws a uniform random number on $(0,1)$ and if it is less than $0.5$ the pair will be slated to collide as long as neither one has collided with anything so far.  If only one pair is slated to collide you will have exactly four left.  What is the chance of that?

If two pairs are slated to collide it depends on the overlap between the pairs.  If one asteroid is part of both pairs, the first collision will eliminate it so the second collision will not happen.  If the two pairs are disjoint, both collisions will happen and you wind up with only two.  You need to compute the chance of two collisions that share one asteroid.

If the pairs slated to collide are $(1,2), (2,3), (3,4)$ you will only have $4$ left if the $(2,3)$ collision happens first.  That is $\frac 13$ chance.  If the pairs slated to collide are $(1,2), (1,3), (2,3)$ you are guaranteed to have $4$ left.  Also if $(1,2), (1,3),$ and $(1,4)$ are slated to collide you are guaranteed to have four left.

You need to think about the sets of three and more collisions that might be slated and which ones wind up with only one collision happening.  Compute the probability of each and add them up.  That will give the chance of ending up with exactly $4$ asteroids.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. I am trying to digest it right now

Comment: "You need to think about the sets of three and more collisions that might be slated and which ones wind up with only one collision happening"                               
what other cases do I need to consider besides sets of 3? Also why are sets on 2 not considered?

Comment: I answered the question for sets of two collisions.  If there is no overlap you wind up with 2 asteroids.  If there is an overlap you wind up with 4.  You need to count the cases where there is an overlap.